# binding to some port with jNetPcap

Tags: port, bind, jnetpcap

I am using java language with jNetPcap library. I would like to know how can I bind to port 5060. I have to make a server program. So my vision is like that:

1. bind to port 5060
2. get all packets which are going to my server ip and this port
3. load them to Sip structure in jnetpcap
   done.

I will be so satisfied if I get all the packets going to port 5060 as Sip.

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the javadocs are not available on the developer's website.  I would start by sending them an email asking if they can make them available as they do not appear to be sharing their source code.

Failing that, it looks like from this link:  http://jnetpcap.com/tutorial/usage, you set the port on the packet itself, rather than when you open a connection.

Failing that, add the JAR to a project in a Java IDE to let it parse the classes and show you what objects are available and what methods are available in those objects.

You might be able to glean enough information from their examples pages.

Good luck.